# Batch file not echoing to file

Tags: batch-file, echo

bat file that should echo lines to another .bat file (). I'm sure it was working fine, but for some reason is not now...

```
echo @echo off > %USERPROFILE%\Documents\Richmond\check_node.bat
echo pushd >> %USERPROFILE%\Documents\Richmond\check_node.bat
echo tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq node.exe" | find /i "node.exe" > nul ||(start %USERPROFILE%\Documents\Richmond\server.bat) >> %USERPROFILE%\Documents\Richmond\check_node.bat
```

Outputs only...

```
@echo off 
pushd
```

It's completely ignoring the last line.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to **[escape characters](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php)** when you want to create a batch file like that :

Give a try for this modification :

```bat
@echo off
Set "check_node=%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Richmond\check_node.bat"
Set "server=%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Richmond\server.bat"
(
    echo @echo off 
    echo pushd 
    echo tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq node.exe" ^| find /i "node.exe" ^>nul ^|^|(start "" "%server%"^)
)> "%check_node%
```

Comment: Thanks! It had to be something stupid I'd missed. Just found it odd it'd ignored the whole line.

Comment: I mean a single quotes symbol? How the hack did you figure that out!